# How long does it take to sync a node or a Daedalus wallet? What factors does it depend on?

Tags: wallet, daedalus, node, syncing

How long does it take to sync (download the blockchain) to a Daedalus Wallet or node. What factors does this depend on (download bandwidth, size of blockchain, upload bandwidth of the source (node))?

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on your hardware, mostly CPU and network connection (yours and your peers), but on most newer hardware you should be able to sync it within a day right now.

Answer (score 1):

As you also asked for a wallet, also note that after your local full node fetched and verified all blocks from the network, your wallet software (Daedalus) may has to restore an existing wallet, and so walk through the whole UTXO history (all blocks)
The more wallets you restore/update the same time the longer it will take

Answer (score 0):

Also can be factor that how many relay nodes the wallet connects to. Right now by default that is only one node - the IOHK server. and that can sometimes not enough since it can be overloaded because lot of wallets can connect to that server simultaneously.
This limitation will be solved by the p2p node discovery will be introduced later this year..
btw, here is a workaround how to define more relays for the wallet:
https://forum.cardano.org/t/workaround-to-fix-daedalus-connecting-to-network-and-syncing-issue/59780?u=laplasz

Comment: Note that IOHK is running several nodes and you are not connecting to only one.

Comment: @MarekMahut-StakeNuts the topology file of the wallet contains only 1 address, so the node will establish a connection only with that address.

Comment: That one addresses resolves to a lot of different nodes. Also, `cardano-node` topology specifies the valency of this address. In other words, it specifies to how many nodes it should connect to from the specified hostname.

Comment: the valency is 1 for the default hostname. Yes, it can be different IP, but only 1 connection will established.

Answer (score 0):

On 1st November 2021, I synced Daedalus Mainnet wallet for approximately 9 hours, and, on 2nd November 2021, Daedalus Testnet wallet for 1 hour.

Answer (score 0):

Daedalus is a full cardano-node exe with a pretty GUI.
When you first start it up, it will connect to nodes defined in topology file, default relays-new.cardano-mainnet.iohk.io

So the syncing performance depends on various factors:

- Your bandwidth and your peer's bandwidth
- Your CPU performance
- Your RAM (every peer in your topology will consume RAM)
- Network status (it can be slower when operations occur on the ledger)

Remember that you can add some of your favorite peers in the topology, but not too much to not overload RAM.